# CSS and Bootstrap - I have done square line css with bootstrap 3 from example but same css with bootstrap 4 line gone?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have CSS code draw square line with bootstrap 3, thanks Kris Urbas for beautiful square line code. Then I use the same code with bootstrap 4, square line has been gone.

How can I adjust css code to work with bootstrap 4?

Below is the CSS code:

```
.product {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

.product__price {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 34px;
}

.product__button-wrap {
    float: right;
}

.product-list {
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.product-list__item {
    list-style: none;
    width: 32%;
}
```

[image]

---

Thanks all reply and answers.
I update my css code. It's very beautiful and so great!!!
Below is my update css code:

```
.image-list__item {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 30%; 
}
```

Comment: What is _beautiful square line code_? Do you mean `border`? Can you share HTML of that block?

Comment: @Jax-p, that's right, sorry for my bad english. it's border.

Comment: Well I see no `border:` in your CSS. It should be something like `border: 1px solid gray;`. Also [Bootstrap 4 has class `border`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/) which do that (`class="border"`). Thats why I also asked for HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1st):bootstrap 4 is overriding your bootstrap 3 code.
(2nd):in your css code there is no border or shadow property used so how can the line be showed if there is no border.